# How can I look up a string in a dictionary which has tuples of strings for its keys?

Tags: python, list, if-statement, tuples

I have this code:

```
import random
greetings_commands = ('hello', 'hi', 'hey')
compliment_commands = (' you look great', 'you are so good', 'you are amazing')

greetings_responses = ['hi sir', 'hello sir', 'hey boss']
compliment_responses = ['so as you sir', 'thanks, and you look beautiful', 'thanks sir']

commands_list = {greetings_commands: greetings_responses, compliment_commands: compliment_responses}

while True:
  user_input = input('Enter your message: ')   # user input or command or questions
  if user_input in commands_list: # check if user_input in the commands dictionary keys
    response = random.choice(commands_list[user_input]) # choose randomly from the resonpses list
    print(response) # show the answer
```

Right now, the `if user_input in commands_list` condition is not met, and no `response` is printed.

How can I make it so that if `user_input` is found in *any* of the tuples used for the dictionary keys, a `response` is chosen from the corresponding value in the dictionary?

Comment: You have two choices.  Either have separate entries in your `command_list` for each command variation, or have a two-step process: one where you categorize an incoming command into, say, GREETING or COMPLIMENT, and then have your `command_list` use those integers as keys.

Comment: that's also helped me. I really appreciate your help

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and note well that this is **not a discussion forum**. We do not generally need a lengthy explanation of the overall program; we want the *specific* code that relates *to the problem*, and a *clear, direct* question *about that problem*. Please note the [edit]s I made to the post to show how it is done. (I also recommend using code fences to format code. If you want to format code using an extra indent, please note that a blank line is required on each side of the code.)

Comment: I'm sorry it's the first time for me to use ask questions in StackOverflow and I'm beginner in programming just 3 weeks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterate through the keys and values of the dictionary, choosing a response once you find a key that contains the user input.

```
while True:
  user_input = input('Enter your message: ')   # user input or command or questions
  for commands, responses in commands_list.items():
    if user_input in commands:
      response = random.choice(responses) # choose randomly from the resonpses list
      print(response) 
      break
```

Alternatively expand `commands_list` so that each key is a single command, to make look-up easier:

```
commands_list = {command: responses 
  for commands, responses in commands_list.items() 
  for command in commands}
```

Then your current code will work.